# Interceptor issue in login and logout in angular 8

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular8, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

In my angular application i have used login and logout concept by MEAN(mongo,Express,Angular,Node).
After login within few min if i reload the page automatically going to login page.Token is there but it is redirecting to login page.I do not know why it is happening like this.Below given my code.

auth.guard.ts:

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from 
'@angular/router';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
 import { UserService } from "../shared/user.service";
 import { Router } from "@angular/router";

 @Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

 constructor(private userService : UserService,private router : Router){}

 canActivate(
 next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
 state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
  if (!this.userService.isLoggedIn()) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    this.userService.deleteToken();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
  }
  }
```

user.service.ts:

```
      getToken() {
        return localStorage.getItem('usertoken');
      }

  setToken(token: string) {
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
  }

  getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
  }

  deleteToken() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
  }

  getUserPayload() {
    var token = this.getToken();
    if (token) {
      var userPayload = atob(token.split('.')[1]);
      return JSON.parse(userPayload);
    }
    else
      return null;
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    var userPayload = this.getUserPayload();
    if (userPayload)
      return userPayload.exp > Date.now() / 1000;
    else
      return false;
  }
```

After logged within 2 or 3 min if i refresh the page getting **err.error.auth is false**.Why it is happening like this?

auth.intercepter.ts:

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from "@angular/router"; 
import { UserService } from "../shared/user.service"; 
@Injectable()
export class UserAuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor { 
constructor(private userService : UserService,private router : Router){} 
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {  
    if (req.headers.get('noauth'))
        return next.handle(req.clone());
    else {
        const clonedreq = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.userService.getToken())
        });
        return next.handle(clonedreq).pipe(
            tap(
                event => { },
                err => {
                    if (err.error.auth == false) {
                        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');  //After login within 2 or 3 min if i refresh or reload the page this is working.I do not know why this is calling on reload the page
                    }
                })
        );
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Make sure your token is set. Look at the local storage. If it is stored, the look at the function `getUserPayload` and see why it returns null. You might have to debug it.

Comment: @Panther: Token is there in my local storage

Comment: You should actually debug. Find where is this un-authenticated comes from. One would be in your interceptor.. and one in your auth guard. See what happens there and trace it back.